# Customize Jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I most likely suspect is not possible but I wanted to know If someone was has worked with customizing the calendar displayed on Jquery UI datepicker to the extend of changing the dates. 
Here is my situation: My company uses a fiscal year instead of a calendar year where and it begins on a different day each year, I actually made an excel calendar in the mean time and I could use the principle on javascript, my question is if there is a way to set up an initial date on the calendar and start counting weeks from that day...

Example

Fiscal year starts on August 28 (sunday), given that :
AUG28-SEPT3 = FW1 
SEPT4-SEPT10 = FW2 
SEPT11-SEPT17 = FW3 
.
.
.
and so on ...
i want to show a calendar with the week number starting on AUG28 2011 (fw1) and ending on aug25 2012 (fw52).

i already read the documentation and I cant' find anything related, if I was not clear enough please let me know so I can rephrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to create your own week calculation, see the  docs for [jQuery UI calculateWeek](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-calculateWeek). Its a start, but not too helpful in those doc's. A little more useful was this [blog post here](http://www.aaideas.com/2010/06/23/week-of-year-in-jqueryui-datepicker/).

Anyway here is the code I have managed to hack together, see the link below to see it working.

Define the datapicker:

```
$("#mydatepicker").datepicker({
    calculateWeek: fisc,
    maxDate: '08/25/12',
    minDate: '08/28/11',
    showWeek: true
});
```

And the function to calculate the weeks:

```
function fisc(date) {
    var checkDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    checkDate.setDate(checkDate.getDate() + 4 - (checkDate.getDay() || 7));
    var time = checkDate.getTime();
    checkDate.setMonth(7); 
    checkDate.setDate(28);
    var week = (Math.floor(Math.round((time - checkDate) / 86400000) / 7) + 2);
    if (week < 1) {
        week = 52 + week;
    }
    return 'FW: '+week;
}
```

[Click here to see this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nbHZW/1/)

I'm sure this probably isn't the perfect way to do this, but it seems to work for this time of night, hopefully it will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: dude, this is just awesome ! it will definetely get me started, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey no problem, glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
$('.dateinput').datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    duration: 'normal',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showWeek: true,
    /*other options goes here...*/
    calculateWeek: function(mydate){
        return 'FW'+(
            $.datepicker.iso8601Week(mydate + 1/*offset A*/)+1/*or offsetB*/
        );
    }
});
```