# Customize Jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wan't to display two weeks in a row in the jquery-ui datepicker, so that it can display a month in three rows. Does any body know how to customize it to do this?

Comment: You can use some jquery extensions available on the net.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896276/customize-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: One could use CSS. The dates are constructed using tables, so one could change the display (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) of the various table elements cleverly.